# Separating Texts in a single cell into multiple cells with Excel/Excel VBA

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I collected data from web scraping using python but it turns out all the review comments in one page is compiled into a single cell in excel. Is there any excel features or Excel VBA functions/codes I could use to separate each data into its own cell?

**[ 
            Mari Russell
         ,

            Olivia
         ,

            Katie Jade
         ,

            Eladi Starr
         ,

            Angela Graham
         ,

            Hillary
         ,

            Ann Hudak
         ,

            Dag107
         ,

            Sarah Summerbell
         ,

            Kelly Sill
         ,

            Lynette Starleper
         ,

            KatherineC605
         ,

            Rachel
         ,

            Odalis Melgar
         ,

            Alisa R
         ,

            Gina G Carey
         ,

            Donna Julian
         ,

            Sharikka Fraylon
         ,

            Elizabeth Marcenaro
         ,

            Shannon Buzzell
         ]**

Comment: Look at `Text To Columns` on the ribbon's `Data` tab. Obviously, you have a comma as separator and you can remove the square brackets easily enough.

Comment: So I tried using the Text To Columns with the Delimited option. But the result is that only the left bracket is left on the original column, and all the other texts are gone.

Comment: Found a VBA code that works. I guess the data here is abit weirdly formatted to be recognized by the Text To Columns feature (or maybe I did something stupidly wrong). Thank you for your suggestions!!

Comment: Please post the code you found and used as an answer to this thread for others to see who may have a similar problem.

Comment: After using `Text-To-Column` operation, the resulting cells (except the first) are likely containing first a newline character then `Olivia` etc.; the newline character makes it appearing hidden below the cell frame and it looks like it "disappears"; makes the line height bigger should reveal it. Consider apply function `SUBSTITUTE` to the scrapped text before applying `Text-To-Column`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub TransposeRange()
'Updateby20140312
Dim rng As Range
Dim InputRng As Range, OutRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set InputRng = Application.Selection.Range("A1")
Set InputRng = Application.InputBox("Range(single cell) :", xTitleId, InputRng.Address, Type:=8)
Set OutRng = Application.InputBox("Out put to (single cell):", xTitleId, Type:=8)
Arr = VBA.Split(InputRng.Range("A1").Value, ",")
OutRng.Resize(UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Arr)
End Sub
```